# Trouble with date format

Tags: r

I am facing a peculiar issue. I have dates coded in the following format:

```
> dateRaw
[1] 1.543072e+12
```

To translate in a normal format, I am using a reference date

```
refDate <- 1.543072e+12
```

Now the following is what's troubling me

```
> dateRaw == refDate
[1] FALSE
```

I am thinking maybe it is due to a loss of precision somewhere, but I do know for a fact. Also I am left puzzled because I do not know how to remedy that issue, which is problematic when using a reference date.

**Edit**

As indicated by @hrbrmstr, the following solves my issue

```
as.POSIXct(1.543072e+12/1000, origin="1970-01-01")
```

Further, here is the output of `all.equal(dateRaw, refDate)`

```
[1] "Mean relative difference: 2.592232e-07"
```

Comment: `as.POSIXct(1.543072e+12/1000, origin="1970-01-01")`

Comment: try `all.equal(dateRaw, refDate)`

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks, that solves it.